# Create a round corner shape in wpf using code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, shapes

i need a round corner shape like the below image.note that when the image is resized, the round corners must not be resized and only the stright line segments must be resized.
[image: img1]

i thaught that i can create a grid with 3 column and 3 row and put each segments of shape in each cell like the below image
[image: img2]
can any one provide a related code to do that(especialy creating the round section in a grid cell) or provide the other solution if you have.
note that i have created the grid in the code and the problem is how to create a quarter round section in one of grid cells(for example round section in row 0 column 0 cell!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example how to create a `Grid` programmatically. Btw: SO is not for asking for code and in the future you should first use the search to find similar questions, try to adapt them to your problem and ask a question (show what you have tried) after these steps when there are still problems.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="root"></Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
Grid g = new Grid();
ColumnDefinition cd1 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition cd2 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition cd3 = new ColumnDefinition();
cd1.Width = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Pixel);
cd2.Width = new GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Pixel);
cd3.Width = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Pixel);
g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd1);
g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd2);
g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd3);

RowDefinition rd1 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition rd2 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition rd3 = new RowDefinition();
rd1.Height = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Pixel);
rd2.Height = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Pixel);
rd3.Height = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Pixel);
g.RowDefinitions.Add(rd1);
g.RowDefinitions.Add(rd2);
g.RowDefinitions.Add(rd3);

Border border = new Border();
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2, 2, 2, 2);
border.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
border.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(15, 15, 15, 15);
Grid.SetColumn(border, 0);
Grid.SetRow(border, 0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(border, 3);
Grid.SetRowSpan(border, 3);

Grid contentGrid = new Grid();
contentGrid.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
Grid.SetColumn(contentGrid, 1);
Grid.SetRow(contentGrid, 1);

g.Children.Add(border);
g.Children.Add(contentGrid);
root.Children.Add(g);
```

Comment: hi and thank you. you are right. this is my fault. i have created the grid in code previously. the problem is how to create an arc in one of grid cells! i could not create it yet with ArcSegment!

Comment: Have a look at my example. You can do this by using a `Border` and manipulating the `CornerRadius` property

Comment: tnx alot. it works well. excuse me for this stupid question. i was thinking for complex solutions. so that i forgot the simple solutions. thank you again